# Обработка @PathVariable с преобразованием String в Integer

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Имеется контроллер, который выводит форму редактирования пользователя:

```
@GetMapping("{user}")
    public String editForm(@PathVariable User user, Model model) {
        if (user.isAdmin()) {
            return "redirect:/users";
        }
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        model.addAttribute("roles", Role.values());
        return "userEdit";
    }
```

Проблема следующая - в базе пользователя создаются с секвенсом от 100000, а потому при подобном запросе:

```
http://localhost:8080/users/100%C2%A0002
```

который имеет ввиду запрос профиля юзера с id = 100002 я получаю ошибку

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'ru.topjava.graduation.model.User'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value '100 002'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "100 002"
```

Топорная реализация в виде удаления лишних символов - не вариант.
Как же это обойти?

Comment: А почему у вас в строке url появляется разделитель разрядов?  естественно что возникает ошибка преобразования в Integer

Comment: потому что он таким в таком виде выгребается из базы. и я не знаю как это изменить

Comment: @MaksimRybalkin, если вам в таком виде приходит - вам ничего править не надо - пусть правят вызывающие. Если там исправить нельзя - то меняйте Integer на String и преобразовывайте в число руками.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В базе он у вас хранится как Integer, а в строке по рест к вам приходит id c разделителем разрядов. Вот здесь `@PathVariable User user` спринг мапит вашу строку `{user}` в сущность User. Т.к. у вас id типа Integer, спринг пытается преобразовать `100%C2%A0002` в  Integer и честно пишет что этого он сделать не может.

ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value '100 002';

Правьте на той стороне где REST метод вызывается, чтоб корректно параметр передавал. Либо принимайте не User а `@PathVariable Integer userId` тогда на вызывающую сторону прилетит 404 ошибка, что метод не найден.